# Axios post does not send data

Tags: reactjs, axios

I am using an axios post to send my information to the backend using Python flask. I use ReactJS as my front end. Here's my call:

```
  sendInfo(){
    var config = { headers: {
                  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'}
              }

    axios.post('/myprofileC',{
      department:this.state.department;
      student: this.state.student
    },config)
    .then(function (response) {
         if (response.data == '/myprofile'){
             console.log(this.state);
             alert('Your changes have been saved');
      }
          window.location = '/myprofile';
      })
     .catch(function (error) {
         console.log(error);
     });
    }
  }
```

I have used the exact same code (with different data) for 2 other pages and it works just fine. However, for this one page, the data did not get sent at all. when I try printing thing out from Python end, I get an empty dictionary.

Does anyone have any idea on what is happening?

Answer (score 5):

You should not set the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header, this is something that is sent in the server response. You also have a syntax error in your code. The following is not a valid JavaScript object:

```
{
  department: this.state.department;
  student: this.state.student
}
```

Replace the semicolon (`;`) with a comma (`,`). Everything else looks ok to me.

Familiarize yourself with the network tab in Chrome dev tools: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network-performance/reference. If the above request was indeed executed, this will give you exact details of the request and response.

Comment: Hi, yes, I did have a ',' instead of ';' for the code, I made a typo when I copied and pasted the code here. I also removed the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' from the header and somehow the request did not send appropriately. The response from that request was what I expected for an empty data. So I'm not sure why the data did not get send right.

Comment: I thought it was a typo, but was just making sure. Are you sure `this.state.department` and `this.state.student` are actually set when you make the request? What does the request look like in chrome dev tools?

Comment: I console.log these two data in response part and I did see the data. I also checked the chrome dev tools and it seemed like no data was sent. The section for data sent with name, status and such is empty.

Comment: Have you set up axios interceptors by any chance? Also, is the data completely missing from the request, or is it there, but just set to null or an empty string?

Comment: If you can get this up on a repo for me to pull down, I'd be happy to debug it locally.

Comment: There is some private information so I could not share it :( but I don't think I have axios interceptors set up. In addition, I used the same POST request for 2 other pages and those work fine, except for this one :(

Comment: Well I still pulled it down and ran your code. You don't have [interceptors](https://github.com/axios/axios#interceptors) set up. The `post` request works just fine for me. I didn't set up the Flask server and I tested the frontend using webpack-dev-server, but that shouldn't make a difference (other than having all requests return a 404). So your problem seems to be elsewhere. Have you tried running this in incognito mode in Chrome? This will ensure there are no extensions or browser state that could cause issues.

Comment: I have a feeling there might be a misunderstanding here and you're not looking at the things I've asked you to look at. When you say things like "it seemed like no data was sent" and "I don't think I have axios interceptors set up", those statements lack confidence and I'm not sure you've looked at the right things :p which is fine, we're here on Stackoverflow to help you. Do you think you can send a screenshot of the the network request in Chrome dev tools for your myprofileC request? I just want to confirm we're on the same page.

Comment: I finally found the problem. I deleted my cached and run the code and it worked. I would run my code from incognito mode from now to save time from this problem. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Woohoo! Glad you got it sorted.